# Show type of post in user's "Top Posts" section in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, user-interface, android-app, posts

In per-site user profiles, as well as the per-site cards in the network profile, a list of "Top Posts" is displayed.

But there is no indication of whether a post is a question or an answer.

Perhaps it would be valuable to add that? Or perhaps separate the two and have a "Top Questions" and "Top Answers" like on the desktop network profile?